# How to get selected item from list Xamarin Forms?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I queried my table to get list the data from my SQLite database. I can list the items but I can't get what I selected. I tried to display what I selected using DisplayAlert. How can I get what I selected? Below is my SQLite table where I got the data (tblCaf). GetActivity() function is the query.

```
[Table("tblCaf")]
public class CAFTable
{
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string CAFNo { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string TempCAFNo { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public DateTime CAFDate { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public string Photo1 { get; set; }
    public string Photo2 { get; set; }
    public string Photo3 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(1000)]
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(1000)]
    public string OtherConcern { get; set; }
}

public void GetActivity()
    {
        try
        {
            var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>();
            var conn = db.GetConnection();

            var getCaf = conn.QueryAsync<CAFTable>("SELECT CAFNo, CAFDate FROM tblCaf WHERE CAFNo != '' ORDER BY CAFDate DESC");
            var resultCount = getCaf.Result.Count;

            if (resultCount > 0)
            {
                var result = getCaf.Result;
                lstActivityHistory.ItemsSource = result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Data Error", ex.Message, "Ok");
        }
    }

private void lstActivityHistory_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var caf = e.SelectedItem as CAFTable;
        DisplayAlert("Selected", caf.CustomerID, "ok");
    }
```

Comment: you are trying to display the CustomerID, but that is NOT a field that you're selecting in your db query

Comment: @Jason I am about to answering my own question with that I reviewed my code and saw that haha

Comment: @jason how can I get the selected item and send the data to next page?

Comment: @lootverge what do you mean next page?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/PassingData/

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
var index = (issoLVHistory.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<TableRow>).IndexOf(e.Item as TableRow);
```

Where `TableRow` is your `CAFTable`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please, let me know if it helps.